# finger vs pointable, when should I use one or the other?

Tags: leap-motion

I'm writing a Leap app and I'm trying to decide whether to use a finger or a pointable.

The API says the pointable works for fingers AND tools.

So what I'm wondering is what's the difference between a pointer and finger and when should I use either case?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use Pointable unless you have a specific reason to distinguish between tools and fingers. That way the user can use either.